# Как разместить виджеты на QGridLayout?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qlabel, qlayout

Возможно ли реализовать расположение виджетов как на изображении 
с помощью `QGridLayout` и `QVBoxLayout` или их комбинации?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, три дочерних  виджета центрируются в зависимости от высоты родительского виджета (высоту виджета обозначает серый фон)

А размеры дочерних виджетов необходимо сохранить без изменений 
(чтобы были такие же как у салатовых квадратов)

Пример моего кода:

```
class SideBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        _width = 60

        self.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, _width, parent.height()))

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)


        self.help = ClickedQLabel()
        self.help.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/terminal.png'))
        self.help.setToolTip('История1')
        self.help.setStyleSheet('background-color: red;')


        self.p = ClickedQLabel()
        self.p.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/terminal.png'))
        self.p.setToolTip('История2')
        self.p.setStyleSheet('background-color: red;')


        self.p_2 = ClickedQLabel()
        self.p_2.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/terminal.png'))
        self.p_2.setToolTip('История3')
        self.p_2.setStyleSheet('background-color: red;')

        self.p_3 = ClickedQLabel()
        self.p_3.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/terminal.png'))
        self.p_3.setToolTip('История4')
        self.p_3.setStyleSheet('background-color: red;')


        self.p_4 = ClickedQLabel()
        self.p_4.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/terminal.png'))
        self.p_4.setToolTip('История5')
        self.p_4.setStyleSheet('background-color: red;')

        self.Vlayout1 = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Vlayout1.addWidget(self.help)

        self.Vlayout2 = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Vlayout2.addWidget(self.p)
        self.Vlayout2.addWidget(self.p_2)
        self.Vlayout2.addWidget(self.p_3)
        self.Vlayout2.addWidget(self.p_4)

        self.Vlayout3 = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Vlayout3.addWidget(QWidget())

        self.layout.addLayout(self.Vlayout1, 0, 0)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.Vlayout2, 1, 0)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.Vlayout3, 2, 0)  


    def paintEvent(self, event):
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor('#202020')))
            painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)

            barRect = QRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())

            painter.drawRect(barRect)
            painter.end()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: покажите, пожалуйста, код, который у вас уже есть и объясните что должно происходить при изменении размера по ширине.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вы предоставили не является минимально-воспроизводимым примером. 
Я понял ваши задачу так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class ClickedQLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ClickedQLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(100, 100)
        self.setText("Hello World")
        
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('_+_.png').scaled(50, 50) 
        cursor = QtGui.QCursor(pixmap)
        self.setCursor(cursor)
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self.clicked.emit()
            

class SideBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        _width = 60
        self.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, _width, parent.height()))

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)

        '''
        self.help = ClickedQLabel()
        self.help.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/android.png').scaled(60, 60))
        self.help.setToolTip('История1')
        self.help.setStyleSheet('background-color: #ce1212;')
        '''
        self.p = ClickedQLabel()
        self.p.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/cartoon1.ico').scaled(60, 60))
        self.p.setToolTip('История2')
        self.p.setStyleSheet('background-color: #f54748;')

        self.p_2 = ClickedQLabel()
        self.p_2.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/cat.png').scaled(60, 60))
        self.p_2.setToolTip('История3')
        self.p_2.setStyleSheet('background-color: #f54748;')

        self.p_3 = ClickedQLabel()
        self.p_3.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/head2.jpg').scaled(60, 60))
        self.p_3.setToolTip('История4')
        self.p_3.setStyleSheet('background-color: #f54748;')

        self.p_4 = ClickedQLabel()
        self.p_4.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/f3.ico').scaled(60, 60))
        self.p_4.setToolTip('История5')
        self.p_4.setStyleSheet('background-color: #f54748;')

#        self.Vlayout1 = QVBoxLayout()
#        self.Vlayout1.addWidget(self.help)     

        self.Vlayout2 = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Vlayout2.addWidget(self.p)
        self.Vlayout2.addWidget(self.p_2)
        self.Vlayout2.addWidget(self.p_3)
        self.Vlayout2.addWidget(self.p_4)

        self.Vlayout3 = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Vlayout3.addWidget(QWidget())

#        self.layout.addLayout(self.Vlayout1, 0, 0) 
        self.layout.addLayout(self.Vlayout2, 1, 0)
        self.layout.addLayout(self.Vlayout3, 2, 0)  

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor('#2020ff')))
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        barRect = QRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())
        painter.drawRect(barRect)
        painter.end()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 450))
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);")        
        
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)

        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Content.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 235, 35);")
        self.Content.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Content.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)
      
        self.frame_left_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_left_menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 0))
        self.frame_left_menu.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 16777215))
        self.frame_left_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);")
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_left_menu)

        self.frame_top_menus = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_top_menus, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        self.sideBar = SideBar(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.sideBar)       

        self.help = ClickedQLabel(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.help.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/android.png').scaled(60, 60))
        self.help.setToolTip('История1')
        self.help.setStyleSheet('background-color: #ce1212;')
        self.help.setFixedSize(60, 60)
        self.help.move(10, 10)
        self.help.clicked.connect(lambda: print('Hello World'))

        self.frame_pages = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_pages)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_pages)

        self.myLabel = QLabel('Hello World')
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.myLabel.setFont(font)
        self.myLabel.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF;")
        self.myLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.myLabel)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(800, 500)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вот что у меня получилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
import sys
import os

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QGridLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QBrush, QPainter, QPixmap




class SideBar(QWidget):
    """  """
    _width = 70
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # self.setMaximumSize(self._width, 100000)
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)

        self.help_button = QLabel(self)
        self.help_button.setPixmap(QPixmap('images'+os.sep+'help.png'))
        self.help_button.setToolTip('История1')
        self.help_button.setFixedSize(32, 32)

        self.command_button = QLabel()
        self.command_button.setPixmap(QPixmap('images'+os.sep+'terminal.png'))
        self.command_button.setFixedSize(32, 32)
        self.command_button.setToolTip('История2')

        self.history_button = QLabel()
        self.history_button.setPixmap(QPixmap('images'+os.sep+'history.png'))
        self.history_button.setFixedSize(32, 32)
        self.history_button.setToolTip('История3')

        self.folder_button = QLabel()
        self.folder_button.setPixmap(QPixmap('images'+os.sep+'folder.png'))
        self.folder_button.setFixedSize(32, 32)
        self.folder_button.setToolTip('История4')

        self.settings_button = QLabel()
        self.settings_button.setPixmap(QPixmap('images'+os.sep+'settings.png'))
        self.settings_button.setFixedSize(32, 32)
        self.settings_button.setToolTip('История5')

        self.top_menu = QWidget()
        self.top_menu.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.top_menu.setStyleSheet('background-color: blue;')

        self.topMenuGridLayout = QGridLayout(self.top_menu)
        self.topMenuGridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.topMenuGridLayout.addWidget(self.help_button)

        self.center_menu = QWidget()
        # Задаем максимальную высоту для центрального блока
        self.center_menu.setMaximumHeight(300)
        self.center_menu.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.center_menu.setStyleSheet('background-color: red;')

        self.centerMenuGridLayout = QGridLayout(self.center_menu)
        self.centerMenuGridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.centerMenuGridLayout.setSpacing(30)

        self.centerMenuGridLayout.addWidget(self.history_button, 0, 0)
        self.centerMenuGridLayout.addWidget(self.command_button, 1, 0)
        self.centerMenuGridLayout.addWidget(self.folder_button, 3, 0)
        self.centerMenuGridLayout.addWidget(self.settings_button, 4, 0)
        # 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.top_menu, 1, 0, Qt.AlignTop)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.center_menu, 2, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(QWidget())

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        """ """
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor('#202020')))
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)

        barRect = QRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())

        painter.drawRect(barRect)
        painter.end()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__()

        self.side_bar = SideBar(self)
        self.side_bar.setGeometry(0, 0, 70, 800)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.resize(800, 800)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```